# How to add data labels to plotly line graph?

Tags: python, plotly, linegraph

I've got a simple plotly line graph:

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.line(data, x="x-axis", y="variable")
fig.show()
```

[image: plotly line graph]

I want to add data labels displaying each y-axis value to each point, but I can't work out how to do it using the plotly api. Is it possible? Can anyone point out how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- have simulated dataframe for your figure
- two steps

  1. define **text** parameter so trace / figure is built appropriately by **Plotly Express**
  2. updated **texttemplate** so that formatting of y-axis is used

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "x-axis": np.arange(0, 12),
        "variable": (np.cos(np.linspace(np.pi / 2, np.pi, 12)) + 1) / 25,
    }
)

fig = px.line(data, x="x-axis", y="variable", text="variable")
fig.update_traces(texttemplate="%{y}")
fig.update_layout(yaxis_tickformat=".2%")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Will check this out first thing tomorrow :)

Comment: @Rob Is there anyway to make it so that the line and text do not overlap?

Comment: @JacobCelestine if you switch to annotations intends of traces for labels you can define x&y offsets.  This is significantly different approach

Comment: @RobRaymond yeah, I went with the annotations approach but wanted to know if it was possible using this approach.

Comment: to avoid overlapping, you can `fig.update_traces(textposition='top center')`